# brute force алгоритм для многочлена, нахождение значения многочлена

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика, typescript

Хочу сравнить скорость работы нескольких алгоритмов многочлена, но проблема в том, что алгоритм перебора не работает. (точнее выдается отличное от первого метода(Метод Горгнера) ответ)
В чем моя проблема и как её решить?

Метод **BruteForce** в коде:

ввод:

> _x = 10 , _n = 3, polyEval = [1,2,3];

ожидаемый результат: 1,2,3;

реальный вывод: 0;

```
    class Programm {

  constructor(x:number, n:number) {
    this._x = x;
    this._n = n;
    this.polyEval = this.RandomArray(this._n);
  }

  private _x:number;
  private _n:number;
  private polyEval:number[] = [];

  private Horner(poly:number[], n:number, x:number){

    let time = performance.now();

    let result = poly[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++){
            result = result * x + poly[i];
    }
    time = performance.now() - time;
    console.log("Method: Horner |" ,`Result: ${result}, array: ${this.polyEval} |` ,`time: ${time.toFixed(5)}`);
  }
  private RandomArray(n: number):number[]{
    let result:number[] = new Array(n);
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if(Math.round(Math.random() * 1) > 0){
        result[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1)) + 1;
      }else{
        result[i] = Math.floor(((Math.random() * (10 - 1)) + 1) * -1);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
// этот метод работает не правильно. Требуется найти значение многочлена выдает отличный результат от правильного
  private BruteForce(poly:number[], n:number, x:number){

    let time = performance.now();

    let result: number = poly[0];
    for(let i = n - 1; i > 0; i--){
      let power = 1;
      for(let j = 1; j < i; j++){
        power = power * x;
      }
      result = result + poly[i] * power;
    }
    time = performance.now() - time;
    console.log("Method: Brute Force |" ,`Result: ${result}, array: ${this.polyEval} |` ,`time: ${time.toFixed(5)}`);
  }

  public Main() {
    console.log(`n - array length: ${this._n} x - coefficient: ${this._x}`);
    this.Horner(this.polyEval, this._n, this._x);
    this.BruteForce(this.polyEval, this._n, this._x);   
  }

}
const random_N:number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1)) + 1;
const random_X:number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1)) + 1;
const poly = new Programm(random_N, random_X);
poly.Main();
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133972/discussion-on-question-by-thrackerzod-brute-forse----).

Answer (score 0):

Давайте аккуратно определим, как хранятся коэффициенты, и  реализуем вычисление
попроще, чтобы не путаться в степенях и направлении циклов.

Полином n-й степени содержит **n+1** коэффициентов, они располагаются по возрастанию степени, так что свободный член лежит в `c[0]`, старший (при n-й степени x) в `c[n]`

```
c0 + c1 * x + c2 * x^2 + c3 * x^3
[c0, c1, c2, c3]
```

Пример на Python, но на JS логику перенести нетрудно, наверное, циклы я на всякий случай в комментариях написал:

```
def horner(cf, n, x):
    res = cf[n]
    for i in reversed(range(n)):  # for (i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
        res = res * x + cf[i]
    return res

def brute(cf, n, x):
    res = cf[0]
    for i in range(1, n+1):  # for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        pow = 1
        for j in range(i):   # for (j=0; i<i; j++)
            pow *= x
        res += cf[i] * pow
    return res

coeffs = [1,2,3,4]
print(horner(coeffs, 3, 10))  #4321
print(brute(coeffs, 3, 10))  #4321
```

Comment: что-то у тебя циклы перевернулись по сравнению с вопросом

Comment: @Grundi Ну я много что поменял - полином n-й степени, он в массиве лежит так, что степень соответствует индексу и т.д.

Comment: @Thrackerzod Не помогло?